# Is every total, convergent function f: N → N is WHILE-computable?

Tags: computability

I am looking answer for the question: Is every total, convergent function f: N → N is WHILE-computable?
In Wikipedia stand, "Every convergent function is computable." But I have no idea how to implement that to this question. How can I show or disprove this statement?

Thanks!

Comment: If $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is convergent, $f$ becomes a constant eventually. That is, there are two constants $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)=b$ for all $x>a$. You do not even need a while loop to compute $f$. Just a block of `if, else if, else if, ..., else` statements will do.

Comment: in script it says only " partial function f : N(power)s → N is WHILE computable if there is a WHILE program P such that f = φP . So I need to write a while program with if else?

Comment: Let $g$ be the constant function 1. Is $g$ WHILE computable?

Comment: I think yes but I don't know how to write the while program for this function.

Comment: Every LOOP program can be considered as a WHILE program. The constant function $g$  is LOOP-computable. You should be able to write a simple LOOP program for $g$; otherwise, it should be a good idea for you to read the textbook/lecture notes/article/whatever where you learned LOOP program again.